# File uploads not working

Tags: php, html

I've made a contact form with an option to upload image. It's in WordPress(my form is a part of a custom plugin I'm making).

Everytime I upload a file, I find $_FILE to be empty.

Here's code of my form.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">            
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bordercolor="#000000" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td width="100%">
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="50%" height="35" >Your Name:<span >*</span></td>
                                <td width="50%"><font size="2" face="Arial" color="#000000">
                                    <input type="text" size="20" value="" id="name" name="formAppName"></font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="35" >Your Web Address:<span >*</span></td>
                                <td><font size="2" face="Arial" color="#000000">
                                    <input type="text"  size="20" value="" id="webAddress" name="webAddress"></font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="35" >E-mail Address:<span >*</span></td>
                                <td><input type="text" size="20" value="" id="email" name="email"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="35" >Subject title:<span >*</span></td>
                                <td><font size="2" face="Arial" color="#000000">
                                <input type="text"  size="30" value="" id="subjectTitle" name="subjectTitle"></font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="35" >Upload Photo:<span >*</span></td>
                                <td><font size="2" face="Arial" color="#000000">
                                <input type="file" size="25" id="formAppPhoto" name="formAppPhoto"></font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td  colspan="2">Body Text:<span >*</span></td>
                              </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <textarea  rows="25" cols="65" name="bodyText"></textarea>
                                </td>
                            </tr>                           
                            <tr>
                              <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit"></td></tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="formAppDo" value="45645645" />
        <input type="hidden" name="formAppId" value="98" />
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reference, it's $_FILES, not $_FILE.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `action` is missing from your form (it's empty). Also, you need to post what you have done in your PHP script.

Comment: if action is empty browser send post request for the same url like the page. yes we need the php code to inspect this

Comment: Guys, I am able to get all the data from $_POST variable.I'm still writing the PHP code in which the $_FILE variable is empty.
I tried var_dump(), and it gave out - NULL

Comment: have you checked your php.ini maybe you have turned off fileupload or maybe you try to send too big file